How to count string's length in Python (if the string includes character escaping)?
There is a string
x = '1a\u0398\t\u03B43s'
How to count its length only using code?
I mean to add before the string r manually is no good
(x = r'1a\u0398\t\u03B43s').
Have tried this solution, but still no good (it counts 9 symbols and should be 18):
x = '1a\\u0398\\t\\u03B43s'
decoded_s = x.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(f'Symbols: {len(decoded_s)}'))

returns 9

What should be the length of '1aΘ\tδ3s'?

s = x.encode('unicode_escape') gives len(s) as 18

'1a\u0398\t\u03B43s' and '1aΘ\tδ3s' are the same. The former means the latter. Your string doesn't contain "backslash u zero…", it contains the character Θ. What exactly is the use case where you cannot write r'1a\u0398\t\u03B43s' but must have it mean '1a\\u0398\\t\\u03B43s'?!

Because you can't convert it into raw string - you can force cast bytes representation to string as follows:
You wish to count what's in between single quotes:
>>> x.encode("unicode_escape")
b'1a\\u0398\\t\\u03b43s'

python-ish conversion is not what you're after:
>>> x.encode("unicode_escape").decode("unicode_escape")
'1aΘ\tδ3s'

you can force convert it to string by casting bytes to ascii:
>>> x.encode("unicode_escape").decode('ascii')
'1a\\\\u0398\\\\t\\\\u03B43s'
>>> len(x.encode("unicode_escape").decode('ascii'))
21

Now with \ it's a bit more complicated - your raw query has 2 \\, but since it's not-raw string it will escape all of them, so even though you see 4 \\\\ it counts 3 \\\ with simple len(...) - therefore you want to subtract 1 for each occurrence (count will count correctly 4 \\\\).
>>> y = x.encode("unicode_escape").decode('ascii')
>>> len(y) - y.count("\\\\")
18


To "strip" the b'...', you should do x.encode('unicode_escape').decode('ascii'), not do manual string slicing on the string representation of bytes.

Encoding using Unicode escapes isn't guaranteed to give you the same thing as was in your string literal. For example '1a\u0398\tδ3s'.encode('unicode_escape') won't yield what was in the string literal. It just gives you some other string.

yes, to the first one, the second - I don't agree it's a problem i.e. that's OP's method, not the literal - therefore that's what we should be aiming at.

I think OP is confused about what they want, and/or it's not clear what exactly the goal is, so not sure how much good this answer does really.

well, it's your gut - I wouldn't make such claim unless I would be 100% sure OP is confused. Even if big picture was relayed insufficiently - task on hand is quite clear, if not for this OP, than maybe somebody else will have big picture making more sense for this question.
